# Why I get empty element in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JS code in function:

```
var selected = [];
 angular.forEach($scope.data, function (value, key) {
     selected[value.Id] = value.checked;
 });

$scope.formDataFiltered.hiddenField = selected;
```

When I do `console.log(selected);` I get:

```
[2: false, 4: false, 5: false]
```

It is right, but when I do submit form I see sending data:

```
hiddenField[]:
hiddenField[]:
hiddenField[]:false
hiddenField[]:
hiddenField[]:false
hiddenField[]:false
```

Why I get empty element in array?

Comment: That's not a valid data structure. Objects are key/val - arrays are a simple list

Comment: Do you recommend to use object?

Comment: value.Id is coming as empty array try to pushs it

Comment: `$scope.data` probably is an object while `selected` is an array: try to use an object as well, i.e. `var selected = {}`. Be careful server-side then, the sent data structure has changed.

Comment: That's what happens when you set an index in an array, it's length becomes the maximum set index, and when iterated you have empty values.